# How to write the following class in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I want to write the following in Clojure, but I can't figure it out for the life of me:

```
new TouchCommand() {

    @Override
    public void itemTouched(TouchMenuItem selectedItem) {
    }
```

I tried:

```
(reify com.vaadin.touchkit.TouchMenu$TouchCommand 
  (itemTouched [^com.vaadin.touchkit.TouchMenu$TouchMenuItem item]))
```

but it returns:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't define method not in interfaces: itemTouched
```

even though "itemTouched" does exist in the interface. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't done extensive Java interop with Clojure so this might be wrong, but how about

```
(proxy [TouchCommand] []
  (itemTouched [selectedItem]
               (.. (getParent)
                   (navigateTo
                     (UiBasics.)))))
```